# Vulkan: vkCreateGraphicsPipelines: Access violation reading location 0x00000016.(nvoglv32.dll)

Tags: c++, shader, vulkan

Im still stuck same problem for like two weeks and dont know what im supposed to do. Im currently writing a vulkan renderer that is simply supposed to draw a single triangle but i cannot figure out why vkCreateGraphicsPipelines throws the same exceptions every time. In case it helps im following these two tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzVFHEmnRLg&list=PL58qjcU5nk8uH9mmlASm4SFy1yuPzDAH0 and https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

```
// RenderingEngine.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
//#include "vulkan\vulkan.h"
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#define ASSERT_VK(val)\
    if(val != VK_SUCCESS){\
        std::cerr << val;\
        __debugbreak();\
    }

VkInstance instance;
VkSurfaceKHR surface;
VkDevice device;
VkSwapchainKHR swapchain;
uint32_t amountImagesInSwapchain = 0;
VkImageView *imageViews;
GLFWwindow *window;
VkShaderModule shaderModuleVert, shaderModuleFrag;
VkPipelineLayout pipelineLayout;
VkRenderPass renderPass;
VkPipeline pipeline;

const uint32_t WIDTH = 1600;
const uint32_t HEIGHT = 900;
const std::vector<const char*> enabledValidationLayers = {
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
};
std::vector<const char*> enabledExtensions = {
    VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME
};
const VkFormat usedFormat = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;

VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT callback;

static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(
    VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity,
    VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType,
    const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT *pCallbackData,
    void * pUserData) {
    if (messageSeverity > VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT) {
        std::cerr << "Validationlayer: " << pCallbackData->pMessage << std::endl;
    }
    return VK_FALSE;
}
VkResult createDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT* pCreateInfo,
    const VkAllocationCallbacks *pAllocator, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT *pCallback) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func) {
        return func(instance, pCreateInfo, pAllocator, pCallback);
    }
    else {
        return VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT;
    }
}
void destroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(VkInstance instance, VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT callback, 
    const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator) {
    auto func = (PFN_vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkDestroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT");
    if (func) {
        func(instance, callback, pAllocator);
    }
}


std::vector<char> readFile(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open shader!" <<  std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open shaderfile!");
    }
    size_t size = (size_t) file.tellg();
    std::vector<char> fileBuffer(size);
    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(fileBuffer.data(), size);
    file.close();
    return fileBuffer;
}

void startGLFW() {
    glfwInit(); glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Tech Demo", nullptr, nullptr);
}

void createShaderModule(const std::vector<char> &code, VkShaderModule* shaderModule) {
    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shaderModuleCreateInfo;
    shaderModuleCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
    shaderModuleCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    shaderModuleCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    shaderModuleCreateInfo.codeSize = code.size();
    shaderModuleCreateInfo.pCode = (uint32_t*)code.data();

    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shaderModuleCreateInfo, nullptr, shaderModule));
}


void startVulkan() {
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "RenderingEngine";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "RenderingEngine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_1;

    uint32_t layerAmount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerAmount, nullptr);
    VkLayerProperties *layers = new VkLayerProperties[layerAmount];
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerAmount, layers);

    std::cout << "Amount of layers: " << layerAmount << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < layerAmount; i++) {
        std::cout << "Name:        " << layers[i].layerName << std::endl
            << "Description: " << layers[i].description << std::endl << std::endl;
    }

    uint32_t extensionAmount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionAmount, nullptr);
    VkExtensionProperties *extensions = new VkExtensionProperties[extensionAmount];
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionAmount, extensions);

    std::cout << std::endl
        << "Amount of Extension: " << extensionAmount << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < extensionAmount; i++) {
        std::cout << "Name:        " << extensions[i].extensionName << std::endl;
    }


    //TODO: Improve adding
    uint32_t amountGLFWExtensions = 0;
    const char** glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&amountGLFWExtensions);
    for (int i = 0; i < amountGLFWExtensions; i++) {
        enabledExtensions.push_back(glfwExtensions[i]);
    }



    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo;
    instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
    instanceInfo.enabledLayerCount = enabledValidationLayers.size();
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = enabledValidationLayers.data();
    instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = enabledExtensions.size();
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = enabledExtensions.data();
    std::cout << &instanceInfo << " " << &instance;
    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, nullptr, &instance));

    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT |
        VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT |
        VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.messageType = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT |
        VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.pfnUserCallback = debugCallback;
    debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo.pUserData = nullptr;

    ASSERT_VK(createDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, &debugUtilsMessengerCreateInfo, nullptr, &callback ));


    ASSERT_VK(glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface))

    vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "");


    uint32_t numberPhysDevices = 0;
    ASSERT_VK(vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &numberPhysDevices, nullptr));

    VkPhysicalDevice* physDevices = new VkPhysicalDevice[numberPhysDevices];

    ASSERT_VK(vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &numberPhysDevices, physDevices));

    for (int i = 0; i < numberPhysDevices; i++) {
        printStats(physDevices[i]);
    }

    float queuePrios[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };

    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo devQueueCreateInfo;
    devQueueCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    devQueueCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    devQueueCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    //TODO: Choose Familiy Index based on fitting properties
    devQueueCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = 0;
    devQueueCreateInfo.queueCount = 1;
    devQueueCreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = queuePrios;

    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures enabledFeatures = {};
    VkDeviceCreateInfo devCreateInfo;

    const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
        VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME
//      VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME
    };

    devCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    devCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    devCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    devCreateInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
    devCreateInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &devQueueCreateInfo;
    devCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    devCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    devCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = deviceExtensions.size();
    devCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = deviceExtensions.data();
    devCreateInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &enabledFeatures;

    //TODO: Pick best suitable device instead of first one
    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateDevice(physDevices[0], &devCreateInfo, nullptr, &device));

    VkQueue dQueue;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(device, 0, 0, &dQueue);

    VkBool32 surfaceSupport = false;
    ASSERT_VK(vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(physDevices[0], 0, surface, &surfaceSupport));

    if (!surfaceSupport) {
        std::cerr << "Surface not supported!" << std::endl;
    }

    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchainCreateInfo;

    swapchainCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    swapchainCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    swapchainCreateInfo.surface = surface;
    swapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount = 3;  //TODO: Check validity
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageFormat = usedFormat;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace  = VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageExtent = VkExtent2D{ WIDTH, HEIGHT};
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    swapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    swapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
    swapchainCreateInfo.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR;
    swapchainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
    swapchainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateSwapchainKHR(device, &swapchainCreateInfo, nullptr, &swapchain));


    vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(device, swapchain, &amountImagesInSwapchain, nullptr);
    VkImage *swapchainImages = new VkImage[amountImagesInSwapchain];
    ASSERT_VK(vkGetSwapchainImagesKHR(device, swapchain, &amountImagesInSwapchain, swapchainImages));

    imageViews = new VkImageView[amountImagesInSwapchain];
    for (int i = 0; i < amountImagesInSwapchain; i++) {
        VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo;
        imageViewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
        imageViewCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
        imageViewCreateInfo.flags = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.image = swapchainImages[i];
        imageViewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
        imageViewCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        imageViewCreateInfo.components = VkComponentMapping{ VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY, VK_COMPONENT_SWIZZLE_IDENTITY };
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

        ASSERT_VK(vkCreateImageView(device, &imageViewCreateInfo, nullptr, &imageViews[i]));
    }

    std::vector<char> shaderCodeVert = readFile("vert.spv");
    std::vector<char> shaderCodeFrag = readFile("frag.spv");



    createShaderModule(shaderCodeVert, &shaderModuleVert);
    createShaderModule(shaderCodeFrag, &shaderModuleFrag);

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.flags = 0;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.module = shaderModuleVert;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.pName = "main";
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert.pSpecializationInfo = nullptr;

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.flags = 0;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.stage = VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.module = shaderModuleVert;
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.pName = "main";
    pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.pSpecializationInfo = nullptr;

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo stages[] = { pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoVert, pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag };

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInputStateCreateInfo;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VERTEX_INPUT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.vertexBindingDescriptionCount = 0;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.pVertexBindingDescriptions = nullptr;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.vertexAttributeDescriptionCount = 0;
    vertexInputStateCreateInfo.pVertexAttributeDescriptions = nullptr;

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_INPUT_ASSEMBLY_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.topology = VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.primitiveRestartEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkViewport viewPort;
    viewPort.x = 0.0f;
    viewPort.y = 0.0f;
    viewPort.width = WIDTH;
    viewPort.height = HEIGHT;
    viewPort.minDepth = 0.0f;
    viewPort.maxDepth = 1.0f;

    VkRect2D scissor;
    scissor.offset = { 0, 0 };
    scissor.extent = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.viewportCount = 1;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.pViewports = &viewPort;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.scissorCount = 1;
    pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.pScissors = &scissor;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthClampEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.rasterizerDiscardEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasConstantFactor = 0.0f;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0.0f;
    pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_MULTISAMPLE_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.rasterizationSamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.sampleShadingEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.minSampleShading = 1.0f;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.pSampleMask = nullptr;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToCoverageEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.alphaToOneEnable = VK_FALSE;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.blendEnable = VK_TRUE;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_SRC_ALPHA;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstColorBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.srcAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ONE;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.dstAlphaBlendFactor = VK_BLEND_FACTOR_ZERO;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.alphaBlendOp = VK_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState.colorWriteMask = VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_R_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_G_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_B_BIT | VK_COLOR_COMPONENT_A_BIT;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_COLOR_BLEND_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.logicOpEnable = VK_FALSE;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.logicOp = VK_LOGIC_OP_NO_OP;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.pAttachments = &pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.blendConstants[0] = 0.0f;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.blendConstants[1] = 0.0f;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.blendConstants[2] = 0.0f;
    pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.blendConstants[3] = 0.0f;

    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutCreateInfo;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = nullptr;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
    pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pPushConstantRanges = nullptr;

    ASSERT_VK(vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout));

    VkAttachmentDescription attachmentDescription;
    attachmentDescription.flags = 0;
    attachmentDescription.format = usedFormat;
    attachmentDescription.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    attachmentDescription.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
    attachmentDescription.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    attachmentDescription.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachmentDescription.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    attachmentDescription.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    attachmentDescription.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

    VkAttachmentReference attachmentReference;
    attachmentReference.attachment = 0;
    attachmentReference.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription;
    subpassDescription.flags = 0;
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDescription.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDescription.pInputAttachments = nullptr;
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = &attachmentReference;
    subpassDescription.pResolveAttachments = nullptr;
    subpassDescription.pDepthStencilAttachment = nullptr;
    subpassDescription.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDescription.pPreserveAttachments = nullptr;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassCreateInfo;
    renderPassCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    renderPassCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    renderPassCreateInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pAttachments = &attachmentDescription;
    renderPassCreateInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
    renderPassCreateInfo.dependencyCount = 0;
    renderPassCreateInfo.pDependencies = nullptr;

    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassCreateInfo, nullptr, &renderPass));

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    pipelineCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = 2;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pStages = stages;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertexInputStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pTessellationState = nullptr;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pViewportState = &pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = &pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = &pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = nullptr;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = &pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDynamicState = nullptr;
    pipelineCreateInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;
    pipelineCreateInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
    pipelineCreateInfo.subpass = 0;
    pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineHandle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    pipelineCreateInfo.basePipelineIndex = -1;

    std::cout << &pipelineCreateInfo << ", " << &pipeline;
    ASSERT_VK(vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 1, &pipelineCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipeline));


    delete[] swapchainImages;
    delete[] layers;
    delete[] extensions;
    delete[] physDevices;

}

void gameloop() {

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

void shutdownGLFW() {


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
}

void shutdownVulkan() {
    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

    vkDestroyPipeline(device, pipeline, nullptr); 
    vkDestroyRenderPass(device, renderPass, nullptr);
    vkDestroyPipelineLayout(device, pipelineLayout, nullptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < amountImagesInSwapchain; i++) {
        vkDestroyImageView(device, imageViews[i], nullptr);
    }
    delete[] imageViews;

    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, shaderModuleVert, nullptr);
    vkDestroyShaderModule(device, shaderModuleFrag, nullptr);

    vkDestroySwapchainKHR(device, swapchain, nullptr);
    vkDestroyDevice(device, nullptr);
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, nullptr);
    destroyDebugUtilsMessengerEXT(instance, callback, nullptr);
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
}



int main() {

    startGLFW();
    startVulkan();

    gameloop();
    shutdownVulkan();
    shutdownGLFW();


    return 0;
}
```

The function can be found in line 549 and i have a suspicion why it might be because its the only thing i did differently from the first video tutorial. 
This shader is simply supposed to return the hardcoded positions but i enabled the the second extension only because the only command in the main required me to enable it. This is the only difference to what was originally done in the tutorial. I tried finding out what these shader extensions are about but i couldnt get any answers to it. There might be another cause but im pretty sure its the shader. I hope someone can help me.

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl : enable

out gl_PerVertex{
    vec4 gl_Position;
};

vec2 positions[3] = vec2[](
    vec2(0.0, -0.5),
    vec2(0.5, 0.5),
    vec2(-0.5, 0.5)
);

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(positions[gl_VertexIndex], 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: *but i cannot figure out why vkCreateGraphicsPipelines throws the same exceptions every time* -- Run the program in the debugger and look at the call stack when the exception occurs.  Then you will know why the exception occurred, or at least what module(s) started the ball rolling to get to the exception.  Also, videos are not a substitute for learning how to debug these types of errors.  That takes experience.

Comment: I did and its the exact same dll i mentioned in  the title, but when searching for it (since i dont know it) i dont get much related to Vulkan. There are some Nvidia forum posts where people incorrectly used vertex attributes but that doesnt make sense in my situation. Of course debugging takes experience but since im lacking that i need some help.

Comment: In addition to that the vulkan validation layers did not print any warning/error etc

Comment: Don't know whether this is the cause of the crash, but it looks wrong: "pipelineShaderStageCreateInfoFrag.module = shaderModuleVert;"

Comment: There really is too much code here.  That's why I gave the general advice of looking at the call stack.  *I did and its the exact same dll i mentioned in the title* -- That doesn't sound like you looked at the call stack, or understood what I stated.  The call stack has all of the routines and calls that led up to the crash.  Your response indicates you're still looking at the module that actually crashed, not the calls that led up to it.  Something loaded that module, and that is what you need to figure out, and the call stack usually shows this information.

Comment: @FloHerick Don't fix the error yet.  Understand how to debug it.  If you looked at the call stack, do you see an indication of that line causing the error?  Did any of the calls that lead up to that crash point to that line?

Comment: You do not need `GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl`. It is enabled implicitly by compiler. I think `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects` neither if on new GLSL version, either way the compiler would complain if it needed it.

Comment: For the love of... don't use naked `new` - `delete`. Either use std::vector, or an array on the stack.

Comment: Thats true, thanks for the hint

Comment: Validation layers did print errors. E.g. your `imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel` is uninitialized, and you state `baseArrayLayer` twice.

Comment: Ouh, you are right. I completely overlooked that. Thanks a lot

Comment: @FloHerick So, set your layers to WARNINGs and ERRORs only.